# Spring Scheduled Jobs executing 3 times in different pools

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring @Scheduled job that runs hourly, but I see that it's actually running 3 times each hour.  Here's the log output that shows this problem:

```
2013-05-06 12:00:27,656 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  src.jobs.NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob - Emails sent from NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob: 1
2013-05-06 12:00:27,750 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  src.jobs.NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob - Emails sent from NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob: 1
2013-05-06 12:00:27,796 [pool-4-thread-1] INFO  src.jobs.NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob - Emails sent from NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob: 1
```

This is obviously really annoying, as three copies of the same email are going out each time this job runs.

**I'm using Spring 3.1**

Here's my configuration:

WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">
  <display-name>site2</display-name>
  <description>Roo generated site2 application</description>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>site2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>site2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

  <context:spring-configured />

  <context:component-scan base-package="src">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*"
      type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
      type="annotation" />
  </context:component-scan>

  <task:annotation-driven/>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="src.domain" />
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath*:**/src.domain</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
  <security:http pattern="/index.html" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/about.html" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/pricing.html" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/signup.html" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/forgotPassword.htm" security="none" />
  <security:http pattern="/**.json" security="none" />

  <security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**.htm"
      access="ROLE_FREE" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/test/**.htm"
      access="ROLE_FREE" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin.htm"
      access="ROLE_SUPERUSER" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/exerciseFiles/**.zip"
      access="ROLE_RECOMMENDED" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
      authentication-failure-handler-ref="failedLoginService"
      authentication-success-handler-ref="successfulLoginService" />
      <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.html"/>
  </security:http>

  <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
      user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
  </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

webmvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="src" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>

    <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
                <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="viewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="src.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="applicationConversionService"/>

</beans>
```

And here's the Class file where the jobs are being executed:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import src.jobs.NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob;
import src.jobs.PayAsYouGoReminderJob;
import src.jobs.RemindUsersToActivateJob;

@Service
public class ScheduledJobsService
{
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("videoJob")
  private NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob videoJob;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("activateJob")
  private RemindUsersToActivateJob activateJob; 
  @Autowired
  private PayAsYouGoReminderJob payAsYouGoReminderJob;

  //This cron just should be set to 1 second past the hour
  // as the videoJob has dates set to be ON the hour exactly
  // example of good setting: @Scheduled(cron="1 0 * * * *")
  @Scheduled(cron="1 0 * * * *")
  public void doHourlyJobs() 
  {
    videoJob.run();
  }

  @Scheduled(cron="0 0 12 * * *")
  public void doDailyJobs() 
  {
    try
    {
        activateJob.run();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      EmailService.sendError(e, null);
    }

    try
    {
      payAsYouGoReminderJob.run();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      EmailService.sendError(e, null);
    }
  }
}
```

* EDIT *******

After doing some more poking around I've narrowed in (a little more) on where the problem is likely happening.  I cannot reproduce this problem in my DEV environment, so there must be some sort of configuration on my PROD box.

My PROD box has 5 different web applications in the webapps folder:

- tomcat 6.0

  - webapps

    - site1
    - site2
    - site3
    - site4
    - site5

I made some changes to my server.xml file and now it only seems to be executing the jobs twice instead of three times.  Here's the new configuration:

**server.xml**

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      <Host name="site1.net"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        <Alias>www.site1.net</Alias>
      </Host>

        <Host name="site2.net"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
            <Alias>www.site2.net</Alias>
            <Context path="" docBase="./site2"/>
        </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: what interfaces does src.jobs.NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob implement?

Comment: Do you have same problem with the daily jobs?

Comment: Are multiple instances of the ScheduledJobsService being created? Could be created twice by the context:component-scan in both the main application context and the servlet configuration.

Comment: The src.jobs.NotifyUsersWhenVideoAvailableJob doesn't implement any interfaces, but it does have a class level annotation @Component("videoJob")

Comment: @kevin847 - I'm aware of the possibility of multiple instances of the ScheduledJobsService being created... but wouldn't that only account for the jobs running twice (as opposed to three times)?

Comment: ScheduledJobsService seams to be a in springs singleton scope, so there should be only one instance.

Comment: @kevin847: I confirmed in my logs that the daily jobs (as well as hourly jobs) are all running three times.

Comment: I notice that all 3 log entries appear to be coming from different thread pools. Not sure if that helps! A few similar issues reported on SO. Some suggest this was a bug in early versions of Spring 3.0, others recommend shifting the task-annotation-driven to the servlet-context instead of app-context.

Comment: I saw the claims that it was an early Spring 3.0 bug (but I'm using Spring 3.1).  I hadn't heard about shifting the task-annotation-driven to the servlet-context though, I'll give that a try

Comment: @kevin847 after switching the task:annotation-driven to my webmvc-config.xml and removing it from applicationContext.xml, the scheduled jobs wouldn't fire at all.

Comment: @Trevor, you probably will get more help if you simplify your code and configs to the minimum that's required to reproduce the problem. The current question requires people to read through pretty lengthy XML documents.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that I can't seem to replicate this problem on my DEV machine.  It only happens in production.  Any thoughts as to what could cause that?

Comment: Does it happen immediately in production? That is, is your application being reloaded by the servlet container?

Comment: @jtoberon I'm not sure what you mean... I know that the problem presents itself upon the first execution of the scheduled jobs after I've rebooted the tomcat server.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering: whether you rebooted the tomcat server.

Comment: @Trevor you said that after changing server.xml the behavior changed? what was the content of that file before?

Comment: @soulcheck the "site2" virtual host entry didn't have autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false".  So as far as I could see, there were two instances of the web app running.  One via www.site2.net and another via www.site2.net/site2

Comment: @Trevor are these two instances of the same web app?

Comment: @soulcheck "site1.net" and "site2.net" are two different web applications... but "site2.net" and "site2.net/site2" were both instances of the same web application (which has since been remedied).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define two web applications in your server.xml, and you're not careful (see below), then you'll have two completely separate instances of everything running in the servlet container.

The context.xml file gives you a way to differentiate between things that are shared and things that are application-specific. The most common example of a thing that can be shared is a datasource or connection pool. This doesn't really help you with Spring beans though.

Fortunately Spring gives you a way to define a shared parent application context, so that beans are shared across WARs running in the same container. It's [pretty well documented](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/) online.

Unfortunately I don't think this works across `<Host>` elements. Virtual hosts allow you to *isolate* resources on the same physical machine, specifically so that the resources can be managed independently. So, if both of the applications define the tasks via `<task:annotation-driven/>`, then you end up with two separate instances.

So, in sum, if you want a single instances of each task per servlet container, then you need a shared application context. Can you:

- Move the applications into one `<Host>`
- Use the `<Alias>` tag with the single `<Host>` to support two separate URLs
- Use the above mentioned techniques to make sure that there is a shared application context

Comment: If it should only exist once, you only define it once in one Host/ Webapp. You can bundle it in one WebApp, or make a distinct "global service" webapp to run such tasks. This need not serve any actual pages! Though having an admin UI is often eventually useful.

Comment: @jtoberon  I only define <task:annotation-driven/> in one applicationContext (as the other web app doesn't use scheduled jobs).  Will your proposed solution still work considering this fact?

Comment: After placing a PostConstruct in my ScheduledJobsService bean, I confirmed that it was being loaded twice.  So I removed all the <Host> entries except the one in question.  When I rebooted, I still saw the @PostConstruct log message printing twice... Am I to believe this means that the culprit is not in having multiple virtual hosts defined in my server.xml?

Comment: Heh, I was pretty confident that the problem was with multiple <Host> entries. If there's only one, and it still happens, then I'm wrong. I may delete this answer later.

Comment: @jtoberon what's interesting is that after playing around with this answer and the one from kabochkov I was able to get the logs to only print the PostConstruct message once (thus confirming that there's only one instance of ScheduledJobsService)... however, then my setup is broken as I'm not able to access site1.net.  Using an alias while only having one <HOST> tag doesn't do what I need.  I wish to have people navigating to site1.net be forwarded to docbase /site1 and people navigating to site2.net be forwarded to docbase /site2.

Comment: I'm confused. When you have only one <Host>, does the job run once per hour as expected? If yes, then it sounds like my diagnosis was correct. I think the easiest workaround here was suggested by Thomas W above: (1) leave the apps in two separate <Host> elements, (2) remove <task:annotation-driven/> from both of those apps, (3) create a third app in a third <Host> that DOES contain the <task:annotation-driven/> config.

Comment: @jtoberon When I have only one <Host> element AND I modify my applicationContext.xml / webmvc-config.xml with kabochkov's answer (below), then it only runs the jobs once... however... then the domain accessibility is broken (as I only have one <Host> tag and am unable to properly send traffic to the site that was previously setup in the second <Host> tag).  Furthermore I currently only have one <task:annotation-driven/> defined across the deployed apps.  So I'm still at an impasse at the moment (but I'll mark this questions as answered as you have helped me out quite a bit already)

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because of loading ScheduledJobsService for several times on application startup.

You can check this assumption by adding @PostConstruct method to ScheduledJobsService with log message.

If so, check that beans (or packages) you load in webmvc-config.xml and ApplicationContext.xml through context:component-scan don't intersect.

Comment: Using your suggestion of adding an @PostConstruct I have confirmed that the ScheduledJobsService is indeed being constructed twice.  I'm going to experiment with this and see what I can come up with.